# Qualitative properties of solutions of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''+\frac{k}{x²}y=0$$

Show that every nontrivial solution has an infinite number of positive zeros if $k\gt\frac14$, and only finite number if $k\le\frac14$.

Comment: Hint: look at solutions of the form $x^{\alpha}$.

Comment: And please improve your post through proper formatting and including your attempts.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by solving the ODE. This can be put into the form of a [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation).
$$x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+ky=0$$
Thus, one should use the ansatz $y=x^{\lambda}$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\lambda x^{\lambda-1}$$
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}=\lambda(\lambda-1)x^{\lambda-2}$$
To obtain:
$$\lambda(\lambda-1)+k=0$$
Solving the quadratic gives the value of $\lambda$, and you can use the fact that $y(x)=c_1 y_1(x)+c_2 y_2(x)$ to obtain the general solution.

Now, you should be able to see why there are an infinite number of positive zeros if $k>\frac{1}{4}$ and a finite number if $k\leq \frac{1}{4}$ based on the solution you obtain.

**Hint:**
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$