# Show the number of roots of the solution of the differential equation $y''+\left(\frac{k}{x^2}\right)y=0$ is a function of $k$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots

Consider this as a known fact:

> For an ordinary differential equation expressed in the normal form $y''+q(x)y=0$, if $\forall x, x>0:q(x)>0$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty}q(x)dx\rightarrow\infty$, then $y(x)$ has infinitely many roots in the positive region of $x-$axis.

Now the equation $y''+\left(\frac{k}{x^2}\right)y=0$ is given and I have to show that for $k>\frac{1}{4}$ the $y(x)$ has infinitely many roots while the number of roots of $y(x)$ for $k\le\frac{1}{4}$ is finite. The only tool I know that helps me to prove such a thing is the above theorem but when you calculate the integral

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{x^2}dx=-\frac{k}{x}\Bigl|_{1}^{\infty}=k$$

It is always bounded. Do you have any idea what is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's Cauchy Euler 's equation

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes indeed it is Cauchy-Euler's equation with general solution $x^m$ and discriminant equation $m^2-m+k=0$, we need infinite oscillation so the roots must be complex. But solving it like this is somehow cheating  (-_-'), I need a way to extract such properties through meta-analysis like the one given above in the form of theorem. For example if it was another form of equation that we have no idea how to solve but still we need to study the behavior of solutions. Also if it helps, it is a problem from "differential equations and its applications by George Simmons".

Comment: @K.K.McDonald https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2188864/93918